# what is the easiest way to take screen spots of an android app?

Tags: android

I have recently gotten a new android phone and it does not have root intill the  30 day warranty is up.my older android has root access but it is my sisters now.i use to use drocap

So what im asking is  there a way were I can take a screen shot of my app in the emulater.i know on a mac (thats what I use) you can take screen spots with command shift 4. But is there something for the emulater in eclipse that I can use to take screen shots?

Answer (score 3):

Android DDMS allow screen capture from an emulator. 
Search for screen capture in the [DDMS tool documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) .